# DotNet Core Azure Search SDK - filtering results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

We are trying to implement Filter functionality into Azure (Cognitive) Search. I was hoping to find some nice SDK methods that hide all the ugly parts, but so far the only example I found looks like this ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search-with-aad#step-2-compose-the-search-request)):

```
SearchParameters parameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = String.Format("groupIds/any(p:search.in(p, '{0}'))", string.Join(",", groups.Select(g => g.ToString()))),
    Select = new[] { "application essays" }
};
```

I was wondering, whether I am missing some docs. Or maybe it is on the roadmap?

Comment: Not sure what you think is the 'ugly part'.  SearchParameters is a breakdown of the parts of an OData query.

Comment: These days in languages like C# you would expect some nice SDK methods that hide all of the string concatenations, escaping control characters and things like that

Comment: You realise all those string concatenation and escaping are because the parameters are describing OData commands, don't you ? Not all interfaces to this API are c#.

Comment: Lol, this is getting funny. Have you heard about the concept of libraries that wrap underlying 'commands' into classes with methods? That way you don't need to learn your OData commands and can use methods instead. Oh, and IDEs nowadays also show you the available methods.

Answer (score 4):

Check out our new [Azure.Search.Documents](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Search.Documents/) SDK we released last month. It does have OData filter helps as you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/search/Azure.Search.Documents/README.md#searchoptions):

```cs
int stars = 4;
SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions
{
    // Filter to only Rating greater than or equal our preference
    Filter = SearchFilter.Create($"Rating ge {stars}"),
    Size = 5, // Take only 5 results
    OrderBy = { "Rating desc" } // Sort by Rating from high to low
};
```

It'll escape string parameters correctly. The OData `$filter` syntax still requires raw input, but the type helpers in the formattable string should make your situation easier: you don't have to worry about escaping values yourself.