# Azure search service with multiple filters

Tags: c#, azure, odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am using Azure Search Service for a Web API. Can anyone help me in passing filterquery to the search service with multiple filter options using c#. (OData with multiple filters). **Exact requirement: When filters applied in search results, the results should be displayed relevant to filters and Vice versa.**

I tried:

string searchServiceEndPoint = configuration["AzureSearchService:SearchServiceEndPoint"];
string queryApiKey configuration["AzureSearchService:SearchServiceQueryApiKey"];
SearchClient searchClient = new SearchClient(new Uri(searchServiceEndPoint), indexName, new AzureKeyCredential(queryApiKey));

```
    SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions()
    {
        IncludeTotalCount = true,
        Filter = Filter = "SalesPlay eq '" + filterQuery["SalesPlay"] + "' And EventPrimaryLanguage eq '" + filterQuery["EventPrimaryLanguage"] + "' And EventStatus eq '" + filterQuery["EventStatus"] + "'"
    };

    var results = searchClient.Search<Azureview>("Local", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the [SearchFilter.Create method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.searchfilter.create).

You can refer also to this older post for an example and links:
[DotNet Core Azure Search SDK - filtering results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62517349/dotnet-core-azure-search-sdk-filtering-results)